# PsychoPy headless on Windows 10

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, headless, psychopy

**Problem:** I am trying to run PsychoPy headless on Windows 10 but am struggling to do so.

**Error:** Currently, my window type is set to "pygame," so I tried running `os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"` at the top of my code, but got: `pygame.error: OpenGL not available`.

**Code:** This is where I specify the window and were I am getting the error:

```
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"

# This line gives the error
win = visual.Window(
    size=[1440, 900], fullscr=False, screen=0,
    winType='pygame', allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False,
    monitor='testMonitor', color=[-1,-1,-1], colorSpace='rgb',
    blendMode='avg', useFBO=True)
```

**Extra info:** I am open to using another window type like Pyglet if it would make running headless easier, but right now I am kind of stuck.
I have thought about trying to make OpenGL run headless instead of Pygame, but I don't know how to do that. If someone could explain how to get OpenGL/PyOpenGL to run headless I could try that.

Comment: I think a bit more background would help. What are you trying to do? Why create a window, if you want headless operation?

Comment: I need to get an array of the window pixel data and display that somewhere else, but I don't want the window to pop up since it is running on a server. Therefore I still need the window to exist, but not shown. On pygame, if you run `os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"` at the top of the script it does this but when I do it with PhsychoPy I get the error above. That is why I am struggling.

Comment: NB: the dummy video driver will never actually render anything, it will just pretend to do so. So you can't ever get an image from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think the keyword you're looking for is "offscreen rendering".

After a bit more digging, I think the best approach is to indeed modify PsychoPy: first, you would have to use a GLFW window instead of pygame, and you need to modify [visual/backends/glfwbackend.py](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/blob/master/psychopy/visual/backends/glfwbackend.py#L302):

In line 302, try to insert `glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, 0)` and see if that works for your usecase.

Leftover previous examples for PyOpenGL: https://github.com/AntonOvsyannikov/PyOpenGL_Examples_SaveToFile

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how I would be able to implement this to my code without editing the source code of PsychoPy. When creating the window the only line of code used was the one above.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about PsychoPy, sorry. OK, now I'm starting to understand. See update.

Comment: I added that to line 302 and tested it. I got no error but the window still popped up, so it is like it didn't do anything.

Comment: When I changed the window type to glfw, the window no longer popped up and it started running headless. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am running on windows 10.